# Without nested switch statements, can we create functional menu in Java?

Tags: java

Im a computer engineering student and I finished my first semester with Java class. I solved hundreds of exercices at beginner levels. But when i tried to create a project from my mind, some errors occured in my brain. Since i know how to create websites and website menus etc., i couldnt figure out how can I create a functional menu without nested switch statements in java.(maybe in passed semester we didnt study that kind of things.)

The problem which I couldnt solve is, if I want to create menu, then every single menu element have multiple elements inside, and all of them depends on user's input for being functional, there will be 100 different switch case operation for me. So I wanted to ask here, if im thinking in wrong way, or is there a better solution for that.

Shortly, I want to create a java program with tons of user input choices and nested switch statements. And want to learn if nested switch statements are the only solutions.

In the following pseudo-code, im writing a small part of my idea which can be extended a lot more. And also I can take experiences from experienced developers about that kind of projects. I found myself while im doing too many self minded projects and most of them are not really a real life problems. But I feel like im learning a lot even with that kind of sillies.

```
 ---Welcome To Market
---1: List selling items in market
       Which one do you want to buy?
       1: item 1
       2: item 2 
       3: item 3 (that goes like that)
       .........
       N: GO BACK to main menu
        (if not enough balance, show user another message and ask if he wants to add balance)
---2: Show my balance
    if its too low, show message to user and ask "Do you want to add balance"?(another statment if, switch..)
---3: Add balance
---4: Show my card 
---5: Exit Store
---Type ur Choice
---here user input
```

Comment: Hi there. It would help if you could share the actual Java code that you're writing, so people can give you specific advice about where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple application where the GUI is the console, yes you most likely end up using switch statements to check the user input.

More "complex" gui frameworks like swing or javafx use callbacks/events to handle user input.

Comment: thank you. i guess im in the beginning of the programming adventure.too much to learn.